# Aggregated Results Unknown Property

Tags: apex, visualforce, aggregate

I have the following code but the aggregate-result doesn't work. I pretty much want to return back the number of active users in the system.
How do I return the Count(*) of all the active users?
Class

> public with sharing class ActiveAgents {
>
> ```
> public List<User> ActiveUsers {get; private set;}
> public List<User> NumberOfAgents {get; private set;}
> public  AgentsNumber[] AgentsNumbers;
>    public Integer Quantity { get; private set; }
> public ActiveAgents() {
>    // User U = new User();
>     ActiveUsers = [SELECT Name , Email, LastName , UserRole.Name , Profile.Name,
>                         Phone , Extension 
>                  FROM User
>                  WHERE IsActive = true];  AggregateResult[] agentListAggregated = [Select count(Id) Quantity
>                                        FROM User
>                                        WHERE IsActive = true ];       AgentsNumbers = new List<AgentsNumber>();       for (AggregateResult ar :
> ```
>
> agentListAggregated){
>
> ```
>            AgentsNumbers.add( new AgentsNumber(ar));
>
>       }
>
>
> }
>  public class AgentsNumber {
>
>         public Product_Lookup__c(AggregateResult ar) {
>         Quantity = (Integer) ar.get('Quantity');
>
>     }
> }
>  }
> ```

VF

> ```
>           <table width="100%" border="0" height="200px">
>               <apex:repeat value="{!AgentsNumbers}" var="AgentsNumber">
>                   <apex:outputText value="{!AgentsNumber.Quantity}" />
>               </apex:repeat>
>               <apex:repeat value="{!ActiveUsers}" var="activeUser">
>
>                        <thead>
>                                 <tr>
>                                     <th colspan="5">
>                                       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                                           <h2>AgentRole:</h2>
>                                           <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.UserRole.Name}" />
>                                       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                                   </th>
>                                 </tr>
>                         </thead>
>                       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                           <h2>FirstName:</h2>
>                            <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.Name}" />
>                       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                           <h2>LastName:</h2>
>                            <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.LastName}" /> 
>                       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                           <h2>Email</h2>
>                            <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.Email}" />
>                       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>
>                       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                           <h2>ProfileName:</h2>
>                            <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.Profile.Name}" />
>                       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                           <h2>PhoneNumber:</h2>
>                            <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.Phone}" />
>                       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                       <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>                           <h2>Extension:</h2>
>                            <apex:outputText value="{!activeUser.Extension}" />
>                       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
>
>
>                  <br/>
>                  <hr/>
>                 </apex:repeat>
>           </table>
>                    <style>    hr { 
>   display: block;
>   margin-top: 0.5em;
>   margin-bottom: 0.5em;
>   margin-left: auto;
>   margin-right: auto;
>   border-style: inset;
>   border-width: 2px;
>   width:100%;
>   background-color: red;  }  </style>             <!-- <apex:outputpanel>
>                     <table width="100%" border="0" height="200px">
>                         <thead>
>                                 <tr>
>                                     <th colspan="2">Filters</th>
>                                 </tr>
>                         </thead>
>                         <tr>
>                             <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
>                         </tr>
>                     </table>
>             </apex:outputpanel> -->
>               </apex:pageBlockSection>    </apex:pageBlock>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of getting the value out of `AggregatedResult`

```
List<AggregateResult> aggrResult = [select count(id) activeUsers from user where IsActive = true];
Integer activeUsers = (Integer) aggrResult.get(0).get('activeUsers');

System.debug(activeUsers);
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the respond, how do I get that  in the VF page?

Comment: Also why do you have activeUser in [select count(id) activeUsers ..] here

Comment: Create a Controller field, perhaps like this `public Integer activeUsersCount {get;set;}` and assign that count. Than later you can refer the field `activeUsersCount` in your VF page as `{!activeUsersCount}`

Comment: That is called field aliasing that allows to specify a friendly label for the aggregated result. See this [https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_alias.htm]

Comment: thank you, I think I may have done it wrong, that I get so many errors here

Comment: I think I am very confused

Comment: If you post your updated source and exact errors/line numbers, somebody will be able to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21517/discussion-between-bez-and-singularity).