# Creation a Formula field with boolean

Tags: formula-field

Here is the story I have bunch of products that they can be added to "Add Quote Item" I want to be able to get all the products that are taxable first (Use a boolean and then the agent will check mark each products and saves it.) then be able to say if there is a check mark on the product add them all up and then multiply it with taxes ... I may not have much of idea
Can we have this formula field 
IF(CONTAINS(Tax__C = True) 
Then (UnitPrice *  Quantity ) * Tax)

Comment: I have a field in QuoteLineItems that is a look up to product Product_Lookup__c and the boolean field in product calls FSLS_Tax__c

Comment: I am assuming you want this field to be on the opportunity? If so, have you tried to create a roll-up summary field then use that field in the calculated formula field?

Comment: roll up summer doesnt show Product table so I can pick my boolean field from it

Comment: can I make a trigger to bring the value of my product to Quote line Item

Comment: You can use a workflow rule to set the value of a text field on the OpportunityProduct to the value of the desired product2 field. Then use that in the roll up summary

Comment: @Eric is correct -- The reason why fsls_tax__c doesn't appear as part of the rsf criteria is that the doc states that no cross-object field may be referenced. You need to use either trigger or wf/process builder to copy the fsls_tax__c field onto the QuoteLineItems

Comment: @Eric  Thank you so much for those information. Ill go ahead and give it try now

Comment: @crop1645 how would you use trigger to pass a field?

Comment: a before insert/update trigger on `QuoteLineitems` can copy the value from Product2 into a custom field on `QuoteLineItems`

Comment: @crop1645 I see, i got it working thank you guys :)  I dont wanna be rude but can you look at this too please :D http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67709/aggregated-results-unknown-property

Comment: @Eric post your respond as answer

Comment: @bez  - Posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comments as answer per request.

I am assuming you want this field to be on the opportunity? If so, have you tried to create a roll-up summary field then use that field in the calculated formula field?

You can use a workflow rule to set the value of a text field on the OpportunityProduct to the value of the desired product2 field. Then use that in the roll up summary

Comment: Do you know how I can take out a price of one time fee out of quote line Item total? Specific product? so for example if I have 300 in total but this total price contains a product that has activation fee but I want to exclude that from 300 . its a unique product